# How to make navigation in Polymer-based apps?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I newbie in polymer-project. My goal is make page like Polymer's Developer guide:

- big articles, each with unique URL without special characters
- drawer with links to articles on the left side

I know how to make base drawer and toolbars, how to make menu in drawer.
But do not know how to make navigation: how to make click listener, how to open article in content area and how to change url of article?

Link to good example or article or doc may be good answer.
I thought that doc to Polymer was made with Polimer, but not. So it is not example.

Comment: Have you looked at the Polymer Start Kit? It has examples that you can follow. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/polymer-starter-kit/index?hl=en

Comment: Yes, I did. In Starter Kit there is menu in drawer, but all content blocks written in index.html (it is not good idea for big articles), and url contains /#!/ in the middle. I do not know how to make step from this example to my case.

Comment: If your articles are in separate files, you could XHR them and update the document with their content. You can use `history.pushState()` to handle browser URL navigation (the starter kit uses `page.js` with hashbangs). There are a few options, can you provide us your code with what you've tried so far and what isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use the [actual docs](https://github.com/polymer/docs) to recreate your own...

Alternatively, you can use the [more-routing](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/more-routing) element to handle app navigation. It comes with a nice video to get you started.